# Algorithm for two real life problems

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, knn

There are two real life problem which I am struggling to find the answer of :

1. **Restaurant Service** : When I use my food ordering app(like FoodPand, Zomato, etc.), the app detects my location when I login and accordingly suggests the nearby restaurants(probably in the range good enough so that the selected restaurant can deliver the food).
2. **Cab Service** : When I use a cab service(like Uber or Ola), they also detect my location when I try to book a cab and suggest the nearby cabs available at that time.

**Question :** 
How is finding the  nearest restaurants and nearest cabs done ? Which specific algorithm is practically used  by them ? Since both cases differ as search data is static in one case and constantly changing in another case.

**My Take on the question :**

1. After doing some brainstorming on the topic, I came to know that since the restaurants are fixed entity, we can map them over KD tree(which allows for storing spatial indexes). Based on the location of the customer, we can perform a search on the KD tree to find out a set of nearby restaurants. The creation of KD tree takes O(n) time and searching takes O(logn) time, n being the number of n odes in the tree. The approach seems good enough to me as I am not aware of any better approach than this and am still looking answer for.
2. In the case of cab service, the positions of cabs aren't static(unlike in restaurant service). So, creating KD tree for every changed locations of cabs seems to be an overhead. How can I find say 5 nearest cabs to me given the current locations of the cabs ? Which algorithm is practically used by the cabs ?

**Any insight will be highly appreciated.**

P.S. : I also came across K Nearest Neighbor search algorithm which again leads to KD trees.

Answer (score 3):

There exist data structure called [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) as a solution to 2D dynamic k-D tree. But in practice real implementation may not involve heavy data structures. You may think simpler method like this one, which may potentially outperform dynamic k-D tree:

1. Divide map into rectangular grids
2. When cab changes its' location(post request containing GPS coordinates), check if it is still in the rectangle otherwise change rectangle's inner information
3. When user wants to find the nearest cab, just locate its rectangle in the grid and find the nearest one with exhaustive search

You may think "why?". In the reality, in the above simple method, it would be easier to add concurrency and parallelization while it may be very hard to modify k-d tree.